# Prove that: $f(x)=0$ has exactly three different roots satisfying: $x_1<0<x_2<x_3$

Tags: limits

Prove that:
If $m<-2$ or $m>2$ ( $m$ is a  parametric)  then $f(x)=x^{3}-\frac{3}{2}m^{2}x^{2}+32=0$ has exactly three different roots satisfying:
$x_{1}<0<x_{2}<x_{3}$

Firstly, $f(x)$ is a continuous function on  $\mathbb{R}$

$f(0)=32$,  $\lim_{x\to -\infty }  f(x)=- \infty$

$\Rightarrow \exists x_{1}<0: f(x_{1})<0$ 
$\Rightarrow f(0).f(x_{1})<0$

After this step, I can't find another value of $f$ to prove the rest of the problem . Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(0) > 0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} = +\infty$ it suffices to find some $x > 0$ with $f(x) < 0$.

The derivative of $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3m^2 x$ vanishes at $x= m^2$, and indeed
$$
 f(m^2) =  - \frac 12 m^6 + 32 < - \frac 12 2^6 + 32 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Try to understand where $f$ is increasing and where it is decreasing. Study the derivative of $f$, this helps you.